# Error on upgrading TYPO3 7.6 to 8.7

Tags: typo3, updating

I tried to update TYPO3 website from 7.6.x to 8.7.x. When I run "Execute database migrations on single rows" in update wizard I get an error:

Oops, an error occurred!
Child record was not processed, reason "[1.0.-1]: [newlog()] Localization failed; There already was a localization for this language of the record!"

More information regarding this error might be available online.

I think this problem is caused by t3blog extension and translated content element in posts. If I ignore this error and run other wizard steps all content is shown on website, but not translated blog posts content elments.

Anyone an idea how I can solve this?
Thanks!
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Running first "Fill translation source field (l10n_source) " and then "Execute database migrations on single rows" seems working